# Helping Solving Generic Array Creation Error (^ at new)

Tags: data-structures

first post here so apologies if I missed something. I'm in a data structures course and need help solving this error. When I run the program below, I get a compiler error of "Bag.java:105: error: generic array creation". I tried creating the LinkedList theArray in a few different ways, but for some reason it is not working. I'd appreciate any help/advice in fixing the issue.

```
public class Bag<T> {

    public class LinkedList {

        Node header;
        Node trailer;
        int size = 0;

        public LinkedList() {
            header = new Node(null, -1, trailer, null);
            trailer = new Node(null, -1, null, null);
            header.setNext(trailer);
        }

        public int size() {
            return size;
        }

        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return size() == 0;
        }

        public void addFirst(T t, int hashKey) {
            Node currentLast = header.getNext();
            Node newest = new Node(t, hashKey, header, currentLast);
            header.setNext(newest);
            currentLast.setPrev(newest);
            size++;
        }

        public T add(T t) {
            Node currentLast = header.getNext();
            Node newest = new Node(t, -1, header, currentLast);
            header.setNext(newest);
            currentLast.setPrev(newest);
            size++;

            return newest.getData();
        }

        public T removeElement(T t) {
            if (isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            }

            T element = t;
            return removeNode(findNode(element));
        }

        public T removeNode(Node node) {
            if (isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            }

            Node pred = node.getPrev();
            Node succ = node.getNext();
            pred.setNext(succ);
            succ.setPrev(pred);
            size--;

            return node.getData();
        }

        public LinkedList findAllElements(T t) {
            Node current = header.getNext();
            T element = t;

            if (isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            }

            LinkedList all = new LinkedList();

            while (current != null) {
                if (current.getData() == element) {
                    all.addFirst(element, -1);
                } else {
                    current = current.getNext();
                }
            }
            return all;
        }

        public Node findNode(T t) {
            Node current = header.getNext();
            T element = t;

            if (isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            }

            while (current.getNext() != null && current.getData() != element) {
                current = current.getNext();
            }

            if (current.getNext() == null && current.getData() != element) {
                System.out.println("Does not exist");
            }

            return current;
        }
    }

    final int ARR_SIZE = 128;
    LinkedList[] theArray = new LinkedList [ARR_SIZE];

    public Bag() {

        for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++) {
            theArray[i] = new LinkedList();
        }
    }

    public boolean add(T x) {
        T element = x;
        int hashKey = element.hashCode() % ARR_SIZE;

        theArray[hashKey].addFirst(element, hashKey);
        return true;
    }

    public T find(T x) {

        T element = x;
        int hashKey = element.hashCode() % ARR_SIZE;

        return theArray[hashKey].findNode(element).getData();
    }

    public T findAll(T x) {
        T element = x;
        int hashKey = element.hashCode() % ARR_SIZE;

        System.out.print(theArray[hashKey].findAllElements(element));

        return element;
    }

    public T remove(T x) {
        T element = x;
        int hashKey = element.hashCode() % ARR_SIZE;
        return theArray[hashKey].removeElement(element);
    }

    public int size() {
        return ARR_SIZE;
    }

    public class Node {

        T data;
        int key;
        Node next;
        Node prev;

        public Node(T t, int k, Node p, Node n) {
            data = t;
            key = k;
            prev = p;
            next = n;
        }

        public T getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(T data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public Node getNext() {
            return next;
        }

        public void setNext(Node next) {
            this.next = next;
        }

        public Node getPrev() {
            return prev;
        }

        public void setPrev(Node prev) {
            this.prev = prev;
        }

        public void display() {
            System.out.println(data);
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Bag<Integer> bag = new Bag();
        bag.add(1);
        bag.add(1);
        bag.add(2);
        bag.add(2);
        bag.add(8);
        bag.add(5);
        bag.add(90);
        bag.add(43);
        bag.add(43);
        bag.add(77);
        bag.add(100);
        bag.add(88);
        bag.add(555);
        bag.add(345);
        bag.add(555);
        bag.add(999);

        bag.find(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is not working. when you run your code, which line throws the error. These kind of details helps find the solution

Comment: Hi Jawad, line 105 - LinkedList[] theArray = new LinkedList [ARR_SIZE]; is the one with the error. Apologies

Comment: you are initializing it in a static way. dont think that will work. Look at your errors again and i am sure it would say something about non-static trying to create static.

Comment: Hi Jawad, I tried initializing it both ways - in either case, the program still does not work. Do you know why that might be?